# Jquery Dialog not open in my simple code

Tags: c#, jquery, entity-framework, razor

What is wrong for the Jquery Dialog not opening when i click in the button?

Below you can see a simple code of the problem.

### Code:

```
@model IEnumerable<TPTMVC.Models.User>
@using TPTMVC.Models;    
@{ViewBag.Title = "Index";}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready
    (
        function () 
        {               
            $("#opener").click(function () {
                $("#dialog100").dialog("open");<--Not opening
            });
            $("#dialog100").dialog({ autoOpen: false });  
        }
    );   
</script>
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog100" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog</div>
```

Result:

[image]

I'm using entity-framework with C#.

### Update

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
        $('#opener').click(function () {
            alert("Click");//It's show
            $('#dialog100').dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
        $('#dialog100').dialog({ autoOpen: false });//After
    });
```

In this case the alert work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dialog100').dialog({ autoOpen: false });//Before
        $('#opener').click(function () {
            alert("Click");//it's not show
            $('#dialog100').dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

In this not.

### The solution:

```
  @section Scripts {
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dialog100').dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        $('#opener').click(function () {
            alert("Bum");
            $('#dialog100').dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    }); 

</script>
}
```

It was missing @section Scripts

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$('#dialog100').dialog('open');`

or...

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#dialog100').dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    $('#opener').click(function () {
        $('#dialog100').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

**EDIT**: based on comments

Use Chrome, hit F12, and check resources to make sure you're loading them...

[image]

Your screen should look like this, only the button displayed...

[image]

The click event should then show the dialog...

[image]

Is this view wrapped in the `_layout`? if so, you are missing a `section`. Usually, the _layout file will have a scripts section, and you will need to have your JS code in this scripts section in your view...

Layout.cshtml

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

view.cshtml

```
@section Scripts { ..jquery scripts..}
```

Comment: $("#opener").click(function () {
$('#dialog100').dialog('open');
});
$("#dialog100").dialog({ autoOpen: false }); unfortunately don't work

Comment: replace your code with my second block, also use chrome dev tools or firebug to see if you are getting any errors in the console.  Also, is this running locally?

Comment: I'll search for a dev tools for chrome, I hope to understand what is happening.

Comment: updated, I managed to recreate the issue.  Use my block of code above.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your set up of the dialogue happens within the click event, so it doesn't get set up properly. It needs to happen outside of the click event.

Here's a working example...

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm. I can copy this directly and paste it in a new file and it works. Do you have chrome dev tools open? Are there any messages in the console?